# Where to keep html pages for mobile app built with Phonegap?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cordova

I'm building a mobile app for Android and iPhone using Phonegap. I was planning to keep all html, css & js files on my web server and serve from there only using webview. I am confused about it. Is it possible to do that or do I have to bundle with Phonegap? I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254009/using-phonegap-and-keeping-the-ui-on-the-server) but this post is one year old. Are there any changes?

Please provide your views.

Thanks

Bhupinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are far better off packaging the resources (html/css/js) with the app. If you load everything remotely you are risking: A) being rejected by at least Apple's app store and B) network latency causing your app to be unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this. you can load css, js and html from server. But it almost look like a mobile website and more over you cannot control the pages with your phonegap events like sensors, battery and notifications, etc., It is purely like a website only. If your net is fast, definitely page loads also fast from loading web server. The main point is you cannot interact users with your app like normal android apps. you can just use like a mobile website. So what i prefer is loading from mobile as package is better and it gives a real application experience rather than a website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it but it will be rejected by the apple app store first. Also in case of network failure or slow internet connection, your application will be of no use. So i suggest to avoid this as this will be a mobile application, not the website.